# Can´t to install Flask-SQLAlchemy with Python 3.5 on Mac

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2 with Python 3.5.4 comand: "pip install -r Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2" but the console show me this error:

*DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2'*

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-r` option you've passed on in the command means 'Install from the given requirements file.'
Since you're not installing packages from a file, remove the `-r` option and run the command.
`pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to put “-r" in the command and then it will work perfectly.

By the way try upgrading Python to 3.8 or 3.9 if possible as it is out of support.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

pip3 install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2

try this